# Swift: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array'

Tags: swift

I have just started learning swift ios development. I am encountering this problem which I am not able to solve. Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong? The image below contains screenshot of the error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
    // creates an array of 7 empty arrays
    var tableData:Array = [[String]] (count: 7,repeatedValue:[])
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func addObjectToTable(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(textField.text != "")
        {
            print (days[dayPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)])
            print (textField.text!)
            tableData[dayPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)].append(textField.text!); // Error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array'
            textField.text = ""
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code within the answer, not a screenshot. It looks like you are trying to append a `string` to an array of arrays... you can append an array to the array of arrays, but you cannot append a string to an array that holds arrays.

Comment: Added the code. Can you please what do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to do

Comment: Looks like you want to store strings in the tableData. Currently you have declared it to be an array of array of strings!. Can you double check what are you trying here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just remembered I ran into this problem a few times when I went back to some old projects that were a bit outdated. For me the fix was simply to change, in your example,

`var tableData:Array = [[String]]`

to

```
var tableData = [[String]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the tableview will contain only days try to typecast the objects Array of AnyObject to Array of String. then use it.

```
var day= self.objects![indexPath.row] as! String
```